# Steps to remove upper tics in the x-axis in winplotr in Fullprof

Tags: fullprof-suite

I am facing difficulty in removing the upper tic in the winplotr in fullprof software. I just want the tics to be below where angles are measured as shown in the image and not above. I tried playing with by going to Option-Frame Features[image], but as soon as i set one say X major axis to 0, it simultaneously remove both above and below tics